# Repeat changing background image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three background images and I need to change them every few seconds. My idea is to use setTimeout, which will replace the background url after checking it with IF instructions and call the function again. Is that good way to do this?
I tried to write it myself, but it doesn't work anyway ehh. Could somebody take a look at it please?

```
            changeBackground();

    function changeBackground(){
        var currentBackground = $("body").css("background-image");

        setTimeout(function(){
            if(currentBackground == "url(/images/new-home-page/woman.png)"){
                $("body").css("background-image", "url(/images/new-home-page/woman2.png)");
            }
            if(currentBackground == "url(/images/new-home-page/woman2.png)"){
                $("body").css("background-image", "url(/images/new-home-page/woman3.png)");
            }
            if(currentBackground == "url(/images/new-home-page/woman3.png)"){
                $("body").css("background-image", "url(/images/new-home-page/woman.png)");
            }

            changeBackground();

        }, 3000);
```

Comment: Do some basic debugging. **look at the value of `currentBackground`** when you do the `==` test on it.

Comment: `$("body").css("background-image", "url")` - **sets** style property, not gets it

Comment: @Quentin currentBackground is [object][object] whatever that means :D

Comment: @hindmost Thank you for this good point. I updated my code to let you know how it looks like now.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve this code by utilizing arrays and using a counter:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var backgrounds = ['/images/new-home-page/woman.png', 
                       '/images/new-home-page/woman2.png', 
                       '/images/new-home-page/woman3.png'],
    $body = $("body"),
    i = 0;

    function nextBackground()
    {
        $body.css("background-image", 'url("' + backgrounds[i++] + '")');
        i %= backgrounds.length;
    }

    nextBackground();
    setInterval(nextBackground, 3000);
});
```

Here is the [working JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/jpfrmpbs/).

Also, note that `setInterval` and `setTimeout` do not guarantee to be precise.

Answer (score 1):

In your code all 3 if conditions are getting executed, so use if-else instead of 3 if cond's ..

```
instead use setInterval()
```

example .. https://jsfiddle.net/m9jbrb5n/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code as base to what you need and change id so it will suit you better.

```
var backgrounds = ['/images/new-home-page/woman.png', 
                   '/images/new-home-page/woman2.png', 
                   '/images/new-home-page/woman3.png'],

var currentBackground;
setInterval(
    function (){
        if(currentBackground==undefined) currentBackground = backgrounds [0];
        $("body").css("background-image",'url("' +currentBackground+'")');
        currentBackground = backgrounds[backgrounds.indexOf(currentBackground) + 1];
    }
,3000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`

```
changeBackground();

function changeBackground(){
    var currentBackground = $("body").css("background-image");

    setInterval(function(){

        if(currentBackground === "/images/new-home-page/woman.png"){
            $("body").css("background-image", "url(/images/new-home-page/woman2.png)");
        } else if(currentBackground === "/images/new-home-page/woman2.png"){
            $("body").css("background-image", "url(/images/new-home-page/woman3.png)");
        } else if(!!!currentBackground || currentBackground === "/images/new-home-page/woman3.png"){
            $("body").css("background-image", "url(/images/new-home-page/woman.png)");
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

`setTimeout()` is called once. You were calling `changeBackground()` inside `setTimeout()` which was resetting the 'background-image' style. Hence, you could not see any change.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes the fully working code.

```
    changeBackground();

    function changeBackground(){
        var currentBackground = $("body").css("background-image");

        setTimeout(function(){
            if(currentBackground == 'url("http://localhost/images/new-home-page/woman.png")'){
                $("body").css("background-image", 'url("/images/new-home-page/woman2.png")');
            }
            else if(currentBackground == 'url("http://localhost/images/new-home-page/woman2.png")'){
                $("body").css("background-image", 'url("/images/new-home-page/woman3.png")');
            }
            else if(currentBackground == 'url("http://localhost/images/new-home-page/woman3.png")'){
                $("body").css("background-image", 'url("/images/new-home-page/woman.png")');
            }

            changeBackground();

        }, 3000);
    }
```